# Reference for general linear groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, textbook-recommendation

I want to find a comprehensive reference on general linear groups, which has depth discussion about its subgroups (like solvable subgroups, Abelian subgroups, and so on). Can anyone help me with this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The question looks too broad, since all sorts of finite and linear algebraic groups show up as subgroups of general linear groups.  So the internal structure of the big group gets arbitrarily complicated.   The choice of field also matters a lot, especially if you study general linear groups as targets of representations of smaller groups.   There really isn't a comprehensive reference for all of this, especially the representation theory aspect.     

Comment: @Jim: Yes, the question is broad in some sense. I want to know as much as is known for subgroups, in particular, the solvable and abelian subgroups of general linear groups to see whether I can use some of the properties for my applications.

@ Mark and Sapir: Thank you for excellent references. Both books are very good. However I think the Suprunenko's book contains more of what I want to know than Wehrfritz's.   

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suprunenko, "Matrix groups", [http://www.amazon.com/Matrix-Groups-D-Suprunenko/dp/0821813412/ref=sr_1_10?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1318007030&sr=1-10](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821813412) .

Answer (score 5):

B.A.F. Wehrfritz, "Infinite linear groups", Ergebnisse der Math. Band 76, Springer-Verlag 1973